# call variable using $_POST php

Tags: php

```
<body onload="cmdform.command.focus()">
<form method="POST" action="#" name="cmdform">
<textarea style="width:100%; height:90%; background:black; color:green;" name="textarea" cols="20" >
<?php 
$name="My Name";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if (!empty($_POST['command'])){
        echo $me = $_POST['textarea'];
        echo "\n";
        echo $_POST['command'];
    }else{
        echo $me = $_POST['textarea'];
    }
}
?>
</textarea>
<input type="text" name="command">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2">
</form></body>
```

When I enter $name in textbox("command")
'My Name' should display in textarea

Comment: `echo $me = $_POST['textarea']` will output '1' for 'true'. `$me = $_POST['textarea']` is an expression, that will be performed and the return is then echoed.

Comment: you want `$me = $_POST['textarea'];` and then `echo $me;`

Comment: anyway, the content of 'command' should be there already. So what is the exact problem?

Comment: 'my name should apear when  form submitted?

Comment: You should start accepting answers, otherwise helping you is not encouraged anymore. None of your last questions have accepted answers, though there are many good answers amongst them. I'm out.

Comment: If `$_POST['command']` is $name then "My Name" should display

Comment: Thoppil... Tip: read Jeff's comments and start acting accordingly you've learned during the SO tour... whishing you a plesant new year, learning curve and enjoy your stay at SO. BTW.. accounts can be flagged for misbehaviour ;-)

Comment: if you solved your own question post it as answer!

Comment: Sorry Jeff Im not ignoring.. I dont know how to ask this question in another way..
for example:
if textarea having some lines
each time i submit the value from textbox will add as new line
but i need when i put $name in textbox the next line should be "My Name"

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with a simple [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/str_replace) call.

```
$content = str_replace('$name', $name, $content);
```

Or you use an `if()` statement to check if the content is exactly the string `"$name"`.

```
if ($_POST['command'] == '$name') {
    $content = $name;
}
```